# I want to get if the user is online or offline, my app will work mostly offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am building a web application that works offline most of the time and i want to detect when the user is online to check for credentials and other security information.

I want to check for these information only when the person is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `navigator.online` method, however, this only detects if you are connected to a network and won't check for the internet.

The best way is to check using ajax while using a time interval method

```
setInterval(checkInternet(),1000); //runs the function every one min
```

```
//pings your own domain
checkInternet(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: document.location.pathname + "?param=" + new Date(),
    error: function() {
      console.log(false);
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log(true);
      //add you function here
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Or instead of timeinterval you can

```
// Will run when a connection to a network is detected
if (navigator.online){
    checkInternet();
  }
```

OR

```
window.addEventListener('online',  checkInternet());
```

Comment: `[...]Also navigator.online only works with google chrome[...]` [MDN: Navigator​.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) and [caniuse.com: Online/offline status](https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status) say something different about browser support.

Comment: you are right, only opera doesn't support it. thank god for edit button

Comment: `setInterval(checkInternet(),1000);`  would call `checkInternet` immediatly and use the result of `checkInternet` as callback for `setInterval`  the same is with `window.addEventListener('online',  checkInternet());`. Although it is possible that calling `checkInternet` returns the actual test function, it is not to be expected due to the naming. And it would not match the `if (navigator.online){  checkInternet(); }`

Comment: It works for me anyway